# How to validate presence of at least one nested object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Code

```
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :questions, inverse_of: :survey,  :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
    validates_associated :questions
end

class Question < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :survey, inverse_of: :questions
    validates_presence_of :survey
end
```

My Surveys Controller

```
def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    2.times {@survey.questions.build}
end
```

Form

```
    <%= form_for @survey do |f|%>
        <p>
            <%= f.label :name%>
            <%= f.text_field :name%>
        </p>
        <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder|%>
            <p>
                <%= builder.text_area :content, rows: 3%>   
            </p>
        <% end %>

        <p><%= f.submit %></p>

    <% end %>
```

As you can see when user creates a survey the form provides two questions, i want user to supply at least one question when creating the survey. How can it be achieve???

Comment: I never tried this, but maybe `validates :questions, presence: true` would be sufficient. I don't know if the built-it rails validation actually test the presence (something like `self.questions.present?`). If yes, then it should be fine

Comment: @MrYoshiji I actually also think, that `validates :questions, presence: true` would work. I would prefer the custom `validate` exclusively because of more control over validation's logic

Comment: @MrYoshiji i also tried 'validates :questions, presence: true' it works but i agree with AndreyDeineko who knows maybe one day i will have to validate 2 question count

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali henners66's answer can provide a solution if one day you want to force the questions count to be different than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options is to use custom validation:

```
validate :questions_count

private

# or something more explicit, like `at_least_one_question` (credits to @MrYoshiji)
def questions_count
  errors.add(
    :base,
    'You can not save a survey without questions. Add at least one question'
  ) if questions.none?
end
```

Basically, the validation will be fired every time you create or "touch" (update) the `survey` object, and it will fail, if `survey` will not have at least one `question` associated.

Comment: In my opinion, the method's name `questions_count` is not explicit at all. Something like `at_least_one_question_is_present_validation` would be way more explicit. But you got the idea, +1

Comment: @MrYoshiji actually started the method name with `at_least`, but caught myself thinking whether I have ever had a method starting with `at_least` - and I could not remember such :D So I think validation message should tell the story about the method, but will edit the answer to include your comment :)

Answer (score 6):

You could just test for the length of the array and simply do:

```
validates :questions, length: {minimum: 1, message: 'should have at least 1 question defined.'}
```

Comment: This solution is way better in my opinion. It uses Rails' built-in validations, can use the I18n default error messages instead of forcing you to create a new one. This is clean for the purpose of the validation. If there is another logic to be done about the questions, then another separate validation should be implemented, containing this logic and not a mixin of the two validations. +1